# Questions about Trump's speech in Long Island

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, trumpism

Two questions about the passage below.

1. What does "Trump riffed" mean?
2. What does "take the hand away" mean in this context?

> When you see these thugs being thrown into the back of a paddy wagon — you just see them thrown in, rough — I said, please don’t be too nice,” **Trump riffed**. “Like when you guys put somebody in the car and you’re protecting their head, you know, the way you put their hand over? Like, don’t hit their head and they’ve just killed somebody — don’t hit their head. I said, you can **take the hand away**, okay?
>
> Jul 28, 2017

Comment: Riffing is improvising. He does. Take the hand away means he recommends not protecting a suspect's head when placing them in the back of a police car, where rushing could bump someone's head. "Protecting the head" is a standard move seen on TV and film. He said it, I didn't.

Comment: For the orange man, it means the typical verbiage. And he can't even get it right: like when you put **your hand over their head**. Geesus, thank god he's gone.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFgjNPiq9Cw The hand gestures the former President make explain what he meanT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Riffing* is improvising. The person in question is known to improvise.

*Take the hand away* means he recommends not protecting a suspect's head when placing them in the back of a police car – where rushing / pushing could bump someone's head. "Protecting the head" is a standard precaution, often seen on TV and film.

He said it, I didn't.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, a *riff* is not the same as improvising. So the online Cambridge English defines it as

> in jazz or popular music a tune that continues or appears regularly in a piece of music while other parts change or are added.

For the verb *riff* it says very precisely

> ... to play a short, repeated series of notes.

Trump often does the equivalent of this in his speeches, repeating a short phrase again and again.  And he does something like that here though it is not a prominent as it often is.  However, there is a broader definition offered:-

> To speak for a long time on a particular subject, especially in a humorous way.

This is typical of Trumps manner of speech-making:  humorous (at least to his audience) and often repetitive.  This is the sense of riffing that is referred to.  There is often quite a bit of improvisation as well, but that is not what riffing is about.

Comment: Improvisation is very commonly a part of riffing, and you'll find it in several other dictionary definitions. I would not consider a carefully prepared comedic monologue to be a riff, no matter how long or entertaining it was. I'm not convinced one can riff by reading from a script.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I agree (agreed) that now the word 'riff" has turned into a word for improvisation.  In jazz itself however, a riff can be part of an improvisation but not the other way around.  So Paul Gonzalves in his solo with Ellington's band in 1956 rises to a crescendo with a series of riffs (repeated phrases) climaxing in a single sustained note.  But in terms of actual current usage, I agree that in journalism it has come to refer to improvisation generally.

Comment: I would suggest "riff" means improvising with intent to entertain and an element of play on a theme .  Improvise is more serious "experimentation" - at least a suggestion of searching for a "solution" ... a "riff" while not quite "gratuitous" (poor jazz improvisation might be called 'doodling' ... more gratuitous) paints a subject purposefully to raise eyebrows or surprise with its path ... titalate at least?

Comment: riff is a subset of improvisation - when used to describe speech generally we're brining to mind a comedian as "riff" drifted to comics from the jazz musicians.  Riff does imply some "method to madness" or err at least being on a theme - if words improvised had no coherence (humorous or insulting, even insults can be coherent) "rambled" or "stammered" or "bloviated" or "yammered" would be more appropriate

Comment: @Tom22 I don't think we disagree. When it comes to jazz composition, the riff is a passage in the score where the band plays a repeated pattern of a bar or two behind the soloist's improvisation.  From time to time, jazz solos may include a riff (repeated pattern of notes (a repeated bar or two) in the improvisation.  It gets applied by journalists in a looser way, more as you describe, to speeches.  No doubt Trump does riff in the jazz sense.  The quotation itself is not like that.  But repeated phrases are a part of his speech making familiar to any willing to listen for any time.